# Invalid Arguement when viewing Dynamics 2016 Audit History

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

After importing a solution to Dynamics 2016, we started getting "Invalid Argument" errors when accessing the Audit History for some Case records.  Mashing the "Try Again" button will eventually reveal an error of "Bad Request - Request Too Long.  HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long."

The odd thing is it isn't every Case.  Those that do show the Audit History state that auditing was turned off (but not back on again), even though auditing has remained on throughout.

Does anyone know what the root cause is, and how it might be resolved?

Comment: Were any audited columns deleted from the Case entity? If so, that can potentially screw up the audit logs.

Comment: A field was deleted from the development environment before the solution was exported, but not from the system experiencing the issue.

Comment: Are you on-prem or online?

Comment: @zipoko Whats the actual error on Event Viewer ? Please add it to the question.
 If you have CRM Tracing enabled there will be more details add them too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did some tracing & the issue wasn't due to a field being deleted as such, but due to the removal of an old SLA.  We had to run a database script to remove the orphaned attributes.  That fixed the problem.